# Infinite Series Convergence and Sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Sum from $1$ to infinity $(4^{k+2})/(7^{k-1})$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4^{k+2}}{7^{k-1}}
$$

So I've broken it down to just powers but then I'm stuck, solutions manual sets $r$ to $(4/7)$ and And breaks it down to $64(4/7)^{k-1}$ and since it's less than $1$, converges.

Not sure how to get there though after breaking into powers.

Comment: are you familiar with Geometric series?

Comment: @Alex yes I've done all the other problems, just stuck on this one.

Comment: It's just a matter of rewriting $4^{k+2}=4^3\cdot4^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your series can be written as  $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty  4^3 \big( \frac{4}{7} \big)^{k-1}= 4^3 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \big( \frac{4}{7} \big)^{k-1} = 4^3 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \big( \frac{4}{7} \big)^{k}  $$
this final series is a [Geometric Series](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Series_Special.aspx), which converges as  $ \frac{4}{7}< 1$,  and its sum is  $$ 4^3 \frac{1}{1-4/7}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use properties of exponents to rewrite $4^{k+2}$ as $4^3\cdot4^{k-1}$ and rewrite $\frac{4^{k-1}}{7^{k-1}}$ as $(\frac{4}{7})^{k-1}$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4^{k+2}}{7^{k-1}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4^3\cdot4^{k-1}}{7^{k-1}}=4^3\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{4}{7})^{k-1}$$

Because $|r|=|\frac{4}{7}|<1$, the series converges.

We can go even further by calculating the sum with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\frac{a}{1-r}$, where $a=4^3$ and $r=\frac{4}{7}$

$$4^3\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{4}{7})^{k-1}=\frac{4^3}{1-\frac{4}{7}}=\frac{448}{3}$$